# Trouble with blade templating in laravel 5

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade, laravel-5

I'm trying to understand laravel's basic blade template engine, but I can't seem to get past a basic example. My blade template is not loading .It only show the white screen but when I remove the hello.blade.php to hello.php it works .Any suggestion?

**Routes.php**

```
Route::get('/', 'PagesController@home');
```

**PagesController.php**

```
<?php namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Http\Requests;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class PagesController extends Controller {

    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return Response
     */
    public function home()
    {

        return Views('hello');
    }
}
```

**hello.blade.php**

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Hello World</title>

    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="content">
                <div class="title">Starting to learn Laravel 5</div>

            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: What's the error message in laravel.log? (storage/logs/laravel-2015-02-15.log)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no `Views` helper. It's called `view`:

```
return view('hello');
```

Comment: I got the same result. Changing Views to view does not solve the problem

Comment: @sixFingersMan Then check your server's logs. Are you using `php artisan serve`, Homestead, or something different?

Comment: ya, this solve the problem but i did not understood what the difference between doing php artisan serve and http://localhost/folder/public .

Comment: @sixFingersMan The difference is, it's a different web server. I don't know why that makes a difference though...

Answer (score 0):

Well, I had the same "white screen problem". And the blade docs in laravel is so confused. Then, try this:

1. Create a layout, lets say `template.blade.php`:

   ```
   <html>
   <head>
       <title>Hello World</title>

   </head>
   <body>
       <div class="container">
           <div class="content">
               <div class="title">Starting to learn Laravel 5</div>
               @yield('view_content') 
           </div>
       </div>
   </body>
   ```
2. Create a simple view that you want to wrap into the template, lets say `hello.blade.php`:

   ```
   @extends('template')
   @section('view_content')
        This is my view content
   @stop
   ```

Now, in your controller just call the view instead the layout:

```
public function home(){

    return view('hello');
}
```

Comment: No luck . This does not solve the problem . But I got the solution .When doing php artisan serve in command line then it gives one link like this http://localhost:8000. When I open that link then this solve the result . But I did not understand what the difference between doing this things .

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how it is working regardless of the extension as in your controller the syntax is incorrect.  You return the view not Views... `return view('hello')`.  You should technically see something like the following:

`FatalErrorException in PagesController.php line 18:
 Call to undefined function App\Http\Controllers\Views()`

Even if app_debug is false you should see `Whoops, looks like something went wrong.`

Comment: Thanks for helping. This idea doesn't work but I got the solution. by using command php artisan serve

Answer (score 0):

I got this when I made a typo like so:

```
return views('abc');
```

instead of

```
return view('abc');
```

That extra `s` was killing everything.